# Bootstrap popover right side alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap popover as some like facebooks new friends , new messages and new activity popover windows . But in my case I have to right align the popover . If I right align my content is not automatically fitting and some part of the message is hiding at the top .

You can see the below JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kXLv5/18/

```
$( function(){
                $("#example").popover({placement:'right',content:'<ul> <li> Friend list 1 </li> <li> Friend list 2 </li> <li> Friend list 3 </li> <li> Friend list 4 </li> <li> Friend list 5 </li><li> Friend list 5 </li><li> Friend list 6 </li><li> Friend list 7 </li></ul>', html:true});
    $("#example").popover("show");
                });

<img id='example' style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);margin-top:20px;" alt="Friends"
width="40px" height="40px"
src="http://www.experienceworks.org/images/content/pagebuilder/twitter-bird-light-bgs_12-4-12.png" title="Friends">
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue ?  ( or any other ways to implement new message popup box like facebook )

I am looking for some thing like below ..

[image]

Comment: Its not about right align the same thing happens on left align .Is it more than a simple margin-top!?

Comment: It looks like that , But I want my Image to be there only . If I give margin-top to image it comes down and it fits . Whatever I gave you is the exact placement of my image

Comment: I just added the image to the question . Please check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite some bootstrap styles in order to achieve this :

```
#friend-list .arrow{
top:0;
margin-top:14px;
}

#friend-list .popover{
top:0 !important;
margin-top:10px;
}

<div id='friend-list'>
<img id=....
</div>
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CB8pr/

Comment: Thanks for the superb solution codeme .. I was looking at after and before and messing up with it .

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the margin-top = 50px approx of your given image.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the confusion , I attached image to the question , I want some thing like that

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id='example' style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);margin-top:100px;" alt="Friends"
width="40px" height="40px"
src="http://www.experienceworks.org/images/content/pagebuilder/twitter-bird-light-bgs_12-4-12.png" title="Friends">
```

Comment: But I want my Image to be there only . If I give margin-top to image it comes down and it fits . Whatever I gave you is the exact placement of my image . I don't want to bring my image down

Comment: Thanks for your response , Just the right side popover should be down . Some think like I mentioned in the attached image in the question  ( I just added to avoid the confusion)